# Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns

Tags: angularjs, parsing

I am having the:

Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns

But my scenario is different. Everything is working fine on my desktop but when I am trying to run the same code on my new laptop I am having the error of

Someone please help me out.

Comment: Can you share more details about the differences between your desktop and laptop?

Or any other errors you might be facing?

Comment: Everything is same... I am using visual studio 2013 on both... I don't think there are other differences.. This is some kind of wired issue? I don't think for Angular.JS we need anything special configured in machine. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I meant more like building processes.
Are you using gulp or anything?

Can you share your code?

Comment: I am using normal asp.net build process using visual studio, nothing additional for building the project. Actually in project, I am using Angular js only for giving multi language support to project,  what is source code look like 
[You can see these special characters are inserted but there is nothing like this in code][1]

Comment: <script src="/ResourceFiles/English.js?sv=11"></script>
    <script src="/ResourceFiles/Hindi.js?sv=11"></script>
    <script src="/ResourceFiles/Japanese.js?sv=11"></script>
    <script src="/ResourceFiles/MultiLanguage.js?sv=11"></script>

    <script src="/assets/scripts/c2m.min.js?sv=11"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/common.min.js?sv=11"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/messageHelper.js?sv=11"></script>sc�������������

Answer (score 0):

I am using normal asp.net build process using visual studio, nothing additional for building the project. Actually project is very big and I am using Angular js only for giving multi language support to project, So I don't think I can share whole code but I can show you what is source code look like 
[You can see these special characters are inserted but there is nothing like this in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ffal.png)

Comment: These special characters inserted into page and not letting other language translation on the page